# Ordering the facet in python ggplot

Tags: python, ggplot2, python-ggplot

I have a dataframe, `df` where `print df.head()` gives:

```
journey_time                  time_stamp    day_name  day_no  week_no
240           289 2017-03-06 00:03:58   Monday       0       10
241           288 2017-03-06 00:08:58   Monday       1       10
242           291 2017-03-06 00:13:58   Monday       1       10
243           289 2017-03-06 00:18:59   Monday       1       10
244           295 2017-03-06 00:23:58   Monday       2       10
243           289 2017-03-06 00:18:59   Monday       2       10
244           295 2017-03-06 00:23:58   Monday       2       10
```

I basically have a series of `journey_time` values for a each day,  range of `day_no`.

```
p = ggplot(aes(x='time_stamp',y='journey_time'),data=df) + scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%H:%M"), date_minor_breaks = "1 hour") + geom_line() + labs(x="Time", y="journey_time (seconds)") + facet_grid('day_name',scales='free_x')
```

This works correctly in that I get 7 horizontal plots. However, the days are not in order (Friday,Monday,Saturday etc). How do I order by the `day_no` record?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `ggplot` appears to put categorical variables in alphabetical order, but you can use the [`category`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) dtype from Pandas to specify your own order:

```py
df.day_name = pd.Categorical(df.day_name, 
                             ordered=True,
                             categories=["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                                         "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", 
                                         "Sunday"])
```

This works as expected in my testing environment (Python 3.4, Pandas 0.18.0, ggplot 0.11.5).

Comment: Thanks @Schmuddi !

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. Trying it with a geom_histogram()+ facet_grid() gives : "python3.7/site-packages/ggplot/geoms/geom_histogram.py", line 48, in plot
params['bins'] = np.arange(np.min(x), np.max(x) + self.params['binwidth'], self.params['binwidth'])
ValueError: arange: cannot compute length" 
I guess it is specific to the geo_histogram...